# Why the prevoius value still exists after reinitialaize variable - PHP

Tags: javascript, php

I came across a tutorial and when we reinitialize a variable that has a value , instead of removing the value , the variable still has the previous value .

I the 3 rd var_dump i am expecting `NULL` , but it prints `volvo` .
isn't this creating confusing things in the code .

```
$carName;
var_dump($carName);

$carName = "Volvo";
var_dump($carName);

$carName; 
var_dump($carName);



NULL
string(5) "Volvo"
string(5) "Volvo"
```

I also saw that `javascript` has the same behavior .

Is this a good feature of the language or a bad feature . **According to my idea , this is bad** , please explain . thanks in advance .

Comment: stating a variable on a newline like `varname; ` does not reinitialize it in any language that I know

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$carname;` does not in fact do anything. It's neither using the variable for any operation, nor is it assigning anything to it. In PHP variables are "initialised" by assigning something to them. If anything, `$carname;` is the same as `echo $carname;` without the `echo`, it's just a [NOOP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NOP). In fact, the first line doesn't do anything either, the first `var_dump` triggers an `Undefined variable carname` notice.

Answer (score 1):

Writing:

```
$carName;
```

doesn't initialize the variable. It reads the variable but doesn't do anything with the value that it read.

You need to assign `null` to it:

```
$carName = null;
```

Comment: Hi but in the first $carName; it prints NULL with out using $carName = null; right  ?

Comment: @KanishkaPanamaldeniya This is, because the variable isn't initialized, so it's null

Comment: Turn on error reporting, you'll see a warning about using the uninitialized variable on the first line.

Answer (score 1):

Latest implementation of PHP totally ignores `$carName;` line.

```
$data;
echo $data;
```

Opcode.

```
line     # *  op                 fetch          ext  return  operands
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
   4     0  >   ECHO                                          !0
         1    > RETURN                                         1
```

http://3v4l.org/c3snU/vld#tabs

Other implementations treat this line as read operation and raise `Undefined variable` notice.

http://3v4l.org/c3snU#vhhvm-350

Answer (score 0):

If you need $carName to be null you should set it as null:

```
$carName = null;
```

$carName; alone doesn't anything.